# Google maps Img tag React Native

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-native, google-api

I am currently working with google Api and it seems that my map is blocked for some reason. I have use a code in the API but i do not understand why i can't move in the map, it is static (as in the code it is keps in an image). I am wondering how to proceed in order to be able to move inside the map and show my location at the same time,
Thank you in advance for your help.

here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps'


import ENV from '../env';

const MapPreview = props => {
  let imagePreviewUrl;

  if (props.location) {
    imagePreviewUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=${
      props.location.lat
    },${
      props.location.lng
    }&zoom=2&size=200x200&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7Clabel:A%7C${
      props.location.lat
    },${props.location.lng}&key=${ENV.googleApiKey}`;
  }

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress} style={{ ...styles.mapPreview, ...props.style }}>
      {props.location ? (
        <Image style={styles.mapImage} source={{ uri: imagePreviewUrl }} />
      ) : (
        props.children
      )}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mapPreview: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  mapImage: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  }
});

export default MapPreview;
```

Here is a picture of what i get: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0hwV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

try increasing the zoom parameter you are using on the `imagePreviewUrl`
So instead of this:

```
imagePreviewUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=${
    props.location.lat
    },${
    props.location.lng
    }&zoom=2&size=200x200&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7Clabel:A%7C${
    props.location.lat
    },${props.location.lng}&key=${ENV.googleApiKey}`;
```

Increase the zoom from 2 to say 15:

```
imagePreviewUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=${
    props.location.lat
    },${
    props.location.lng
    }&zoom=15&size=200x200&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7Clabel:A%7C${
    props.location.lat
    },${props.location.lng}&key=${ENV.googleApiKey}`;
```

Hope this Helps!